# how to connect PHPStorm with xampp on windows7?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I don't even know if I asked the right question or what, but I have made a database before with phpmyadmin before I start using "PHPStorm", how ever there is no error giving in my code, here it is:

```
   <?php
try {
    $handler = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=Database', 'root', 'password');
    $handler -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOExeption $e)
{
    die('Sorry, Database problem');
}
$query = $handler->query('select * from users;');

while($r= $query->fetch())
{
    echo $r['name'];
}
?>
```

but there is no output giving, I'm pretty sure that there is data in my database, one more thing; xampp and phpstorm exist in deterrent folders.
Thanks in advance :).

Comment: What happens when you go into phpmyadmin and run the above SQL query `select * from users;`?

Comment: I would add a comment (`echo "now finished";`) at the end to make sure you are executing all the code.  Also try `echo $r[0];` (or some other index depending on where name column is),

Comment: Thank you dude, I found the solution here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE 
thaks for your help anyway

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference regarding connection itself but I suggest you get rid of the try / catch /die pattern. Instead, ensure you've configured PHP to *display* error messages on screen in your development box (you can trigger an intentional notice to verify that, e.g. `$non_existing_variable++;`). This has really nothing to do with your IDE.